# document.referrer is empty between two https

Tags: javascript, url, https, referrer, referer

Referer is empty when it redirects from two https websites

```
http://site0.gb => 302 redirect => https://site1.co => 302 redirect => https://site2.com => document.referrer is empty
```

all of the websites Header Settings are `Referrer-Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade`

It is strange becasuse in [Referrer-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy)

```
no-referrer-when-downgrade : https://example.com/page.html -> https://mozilla.org
```

> document.referrer is https://example.com/page.html

## How to make it working. Can I get document.referrer of `https://site1.co`? And what the reason of empty referrer?

Comment: Note that [`document.referrer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer) is not necessarily the same as the `Referer` header (which is what the Referrer-Policy controls).  Also, note the text on th document.referrer page: "The value is an empty string if the user navigated to the page directly (not through a link, but, for example, by using a bookmark)". I expect that a 302 redirect is not "navigat[ing] to the page directly".

Comment: Yes, I know about that. I've tested also this situation on other domains like `http://domain1.com` to `https://domain2.com` with 302 redirect and it works fine. `document.referrer` is sending between this domains

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is the exact reason why it is considered bad practice to use too many 302 redirects rather than using something like mod rewrite or some other server-side system to forward web pages.

You can also use the server config files to include the original referrer on some servers.

You are better off doing something like setting the header before the page loads using PHP or making a POST  request with the old referrer to the new URL if none is given with  javascript.

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps this issue is related to server properties. Cause I saw at google redirects between https domains after search. And it looks fine. Anyway thanks for answer.